# slick слайдер, слайд по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('.project__slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
    asNavFor: '.project__carusel',
  });
  $('.project__slider').on('click',function(){
    $(this).slick('slickNext');
  });

  $('.project__carusel').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    dots: false,
    arrows: false,
    asNavFor: '.project__slider',
    focusOnSelect: true,
   variableWidth: true
  });
```

```html
<div class="project">
          <div class="project__slider">
                <div class="project__img-block">
                  <img class="project__images" src="http://studiya-remontov.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Современная-гостиная-в-европейском-стиле.png"/>
                </div>
         </div>
         <div class="project__carusel">
               <div class="project__carusel-conteiner">
                  <img class="project__images-car" src="http://studiya-remontov.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Современная-гостиная-в-европейском-стиле.png"/>
               </div>
         </div>
       </div>
```

При клике на сам слайдер у меня крутится каруселька + переключается слайд. Теперь сам вопрос: Нужно сделать так что бы, если в каруселька только 3 слайда сама каруселька не крутилась при клике на сам слайдер.

Comment: максим пишется с x = maxim

Comment: Вот это поворот

Comment: а что происходит при нажатии на слайдер сейчас? если в карусели 3 слайда?

Comment: как вариант - перед тем как вы инициализируете slick - проверять кол-во в карусельке, в зависимости от кол-ва устанавливать или не устанавливать значение в asNavFor

Comment: @Skywave - При клике на слайдер каруселька тоже крутится, то-есть если 3 слайда в карусельке, то при клике на слайдер каруселька крутится на слайд. И получается что остается пустое пространство. А когда слайдер возвращается к первому сладу то каруселька опять выводит 3 слайда.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example